# difference between multiple OpenCV documentation pages

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, opencv3.0

I've been using OpenCV for 6 months. However, the following question just came up to my mind:

What is the difference between the follwing OpenCV pages, are they all refered as  official?

1-  http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.1_org/py/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography

2-  https://opencv.org/

3-  https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don’t know what opencv.jp is, opencv.org is the official site. In any case, link 1 is docs for version 2.1, and link 3 is docs for the latest version (currently 4.5).

Comment: Opencv version 2.x (link 1) is no longer used, now we only use opencv2 version 3.x and 4.x, or a lot of new features have been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got me wondering; never really thought about this for opencv.jp though I have used it in the past.

I've checked the about section of the page, roughly translated into English (by google) it says:

> opencv.jp is an unofficial site created by Japanese opencv users. If
> you have any opinions or suggestions regarding the contents of this
> site, please contact the forum on the site or the following e-mail
> address.

So in order:

1. Unofficial (Japanese) site created by OpenCV users, it mostly contains documentation with code examples
2. This is the official general homepage
3. Official documentation for 4.5, as @Chris Luego already pointed out in the comments

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I guess this is totally enough for me